# Host a separate origin repo

Tags: git, github

I need to use a public `project A` on GitHub into my project, with some modifications that I cannot check into GitHub and mess up the original author's work, but I do need to pull down the author's updates into my company.

I am wondering how I can host a satellite Git repo in my company while keep it as our own origin and get updates from the real origin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Consider using Git submodules

The question is a little unclear, but it sounds like you might have your own Git repo, but you want to include a 3rd-party Git repo in your code as a library. One option that you have is to use [Git Submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/ch6-6.html). I've never used one of these before, so you'll have to read up on how they work.

I've also heard that another option is `git subtree`, but this is also something I've never used before, and it's also not currently documented in the [main Git documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/). You can learn more about `subtree` from [Alternatives To Git Submodule: Git Subtree](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/05/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree/).

---

### Old answer, but still has useful info

#### Adding upstream repo as a remote

The question is a little unclear, but it sounds like you basically just want to make a company fork of a project on GitHub to act as your origin, but you still want to fetch commits from the original repo. The term that GitHub uses for the original remote source repo is the `upstream` repo, which you can just add as another remote to any clone:

```
git remote add upstream <url-of-original-repo>
```

Then just fetch the changes from `upstream`, and merge it in with your origin commits, or rebase your work on top of it, or whatever else you want to do:

```
git fetch upstream
git checkout -b master origin/master
git merge upstream/master
git push origin master
```

As the [GitHub Help Page "Fork a Repo"](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo) states (emphasis mine):

> When a repository is cloned, it has a default remote called **origin** that points to your fork on GitHub, not the original repository it was forked from. **To keep track of the original repository, you need to add another remote named `upstream`**:
>
> ```
> cd Spoon-Knife
> git remote add upstream https://github.com/octocat/Spoon-Knife.git
> git fetch upstream
> ```
>
> ***If the original repository you forked your project from gets updated, you can add those updates to your fork by running the following code***:
>
> ```
> # Fetches any new changes from the original repository
> git fetch upstream
> # Merges any changes fetched into your working files
> git merge upstream/master
> ```

Comment: @Feng I forgot to mention, you should also consider using the public project that you want to include as a [Git submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/ch6-6.html).

Comment: remember you need to recommit any modified source to a public repository if the project's license requires it.

Comment: You can learn more about various licenses from GitHub's [ChooseALicense.com](http://choosealicense.com/). Some of them are very liberal with what you're allowed to do with the source code, like the [MIT License](http://choosealicense.com/licenses/mit/). [jQuery](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/2.0.3/MIT-LICENSE.txt) and [Ruby on Rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/README.md#license) both use the MIT License, for example.

Answer (score 1):

`git remote add myremote ssh@your.githost.com/repo` will add a new origin repo.

Depending on the license, however, it's probably not legal to modify the source for use in your company without providing the modified source in a public location. If the license for the GitHub repo your cloning is GPL etc, your best bet is to just fork the project on GitHub.

Comment: Some licenses are very liberal. Take the [MIT License](http://choosealicense.com/licenses/mit/) for example. You can pretty much do whatever you want with it, including selling the software commercially(!), as long as you basically give credit to the original author, and don't hold them liable if the software doesn't work or causes damage. [jQuery](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/2.0.3/MIT-LICENSE.txt) and [Ruby on Rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/README.md#license) both use the MIT License, for example.